# Could not find specific file in R package "earth"

Tags: r, package

I am currently working on the Multivariate Adaptative Regression Splines model, however I am struggling a bit to understand the algorithm (especially understanding how are the basis functions chosen at each step and in which order)  and therefore would like to check the source code of the R package "earth".

I am interested in the forward pass so I tried to find out which functions computed it. I found out thanks to the command getAnywhere() that the file which interests me is "ForwardPassR" with I guess a .c extension.

```
getAnywhere(forward.pass)
  >>rv <- .C("ForwardPassR", fullset = as.integer(fullset), bx = matrix(0,....
```

(I just put the line which is interesting to me in the output).

But this file is no where to be found in the archive I downloaded on the CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/package=earth).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to get the source for the package and search

Comment: That’s not (necessarily) a file, it’s a *function name* in C.

Comment: @42- Already did. If it is not the file but the function how can I then have access to this function (and its source code) should not it be downloaded with the package ?

Comment: here is a github link that has what you are looking for: https://github.com/cran/earth

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.